# apple 10.9.1 MS office two screens simultaneously working on MS word on one screen and PPT on the other

Tags: mac, ms-office, screen

I cant have the two applications visible at the same time, one on each screen. The full double screens switches every time I switch application, it is very inconvenient, any idea  on how to avoid that? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you activate "Displays have separate Spaces" in the "Mission Control" Preference Pane in the System Preferences (logout is required), you can use booth screens with an fullscreen applications (CTRL-CMD-F).

I tested this under OS X 10.9.1 with MS Word 2011 v.14.3.8 and MS PowerPoint 2011 v.14.3.8.